# How to use more than one keyboard with different layouts?

Tags: keyboard, language, keyboard-layout

I type in many languages, and switching between them is a waste of time.

I would like to use several physical keyboards for different languages.

So is it possible to use two or more keyboards at the same time?

Comment: Any particular OS?

Answer (score -1):

Based on the simplicity of your question, a short and simple answer is no in windows and yes in say, Ubuntu. 
However; Windows has short cuts for switching between the layouts and should remove the [waste of time](http://cdn.viralscape.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Walking-Dad-Joke-30.jpg) element.

Google is very helpful on the subject: [Two Keyboards Two Languages](https://www.google.dk/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C1GGRV_enDK751DK751&q=windows%2010%20shortcut%20keyboard%20language&oq=windows%2010%20shortcut%20keyboard%20language&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i8i30k1l3.43093.43252.0.43380.3.3.0.0.0.0.98.260.3.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.2.167...0i7i30k1j0i8i7i30k1.8PU4bj-Ixpc)

Also a dublicate to [How, in Windows 10, do I have two keyboards...](https://superuser.com/questions/970462/how-in-windows-10-do-i-have-two-keyboards-each-of-which-automatically-uses-a-s)

Default Short cut is LeftAlt+Shift