# `us altgr-intl` layout on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, international

Is there a US international keyboard layout variant for Windows 10 that behaves like `altgr-intl` on Linux? That is, if I press `'` it appears on-screen immediately (no deadkey), and if I want to type <kbd>E</kbd> I need to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+' followed by <kbd>E</kbd>.

I don't mind downloading it from a third-party.

Comment: [US International Keyboard Layout w/o Dead Keys for Microsoft Windows](https://blog.ginkel.com/2010/05/us-international-keyboard-layout-wo-dead-keys-for-microsoft-windows/)

Comment: @DavidPostill The download link is a 404...

Comment: Try contacting the blog author?

Comment: @DavidPostill Also, from the description it looks like the author simply removed the deadkeys, instead of moving them to `altgr+key`. So I suppose it's going to be impossible to type `é` on this layout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you can get what you want under United States International Alternate:

http://keyboards.jargon-file.org/

You can install it either through the executable or you can opt for the KLC source file(s) and install the layout with Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator.

Comment: Don't know why it got a downvote, but it seems exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: it's probably a -1 because it's just a list of keyboard installers that will trigger your corporate virus scanner, and it doesn't give any specifics on how to get the source file or install `us altgr-intl` on windows 10.

Comment: From user [Lu Tao](https://superuser.com/users/590814/lu-tao): For this method to work in Windows 10, just reboot after the setup.exe is done, the added keyboard will show in the list of available layouts under `Region & Language settings > Click on current keyboard > Options > Add a Keyboard`

Comment: This method is still working perfectly on win 10 in november 2020. Thanks, nothing else worked for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/thomasfaingnaert/win-us-intl-altgr has a Windows port of this exact keyboard layout, with source.

Answer (score 2):

Another method is using an [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script.
When you want to find out more about this method, please also take a look at the [UltimateKEYS](https://pieter-degroote.github.io/UltimateKEYS/) website and its [GitHUB repository](https://github.com/pieter-degroote/UltimateKEYS).

This is a project which I developed (based on [EurKEY](https://eurkey.steffen.bruentjen.eu/)) and which *attempts to harmonize* languages with Latin-based alphabets on US QWERTY, having the dead key combinations, etc. on <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

This is the UltimateKEYS Keyboard Layout:

[image: UltimateKEYS Keyboard Layout]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to @norok2 you can create any keyboard layout using [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339). Here's my step-by-step for Windows 10

- Download and install
- Open software and `Load Existing Keyboard...` from `File` menu. In my case I loaded  US-International and saved it as US-International-AltGr (not rewriting original)
- Right click over quote keys and remove `Set as dead key` flag
- Check Shift States' `Shift` and uncheck dead keys again
- **Optinal**: You can test under `Project > Test Keyboard Layout`
- Once pleased, go to `Project > Build DLL and Setup Page`. It will check everything's alright and open created files
- Click `setup.exe` and follow simple wizard
- **Important**: Reset your PC. Found weird behavior in VSC before this

*This was written with my new keyboard layout ;)*